# JQUERY ON('change') get checkbox value and state

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

How can I "get" the checkbox that changed inside div "containerDIV"?

View:

```
@model MyModel

<div id="containerDIV">
<ul id="CheckBoxList">
@foreach (XObject t in MyModel.XCollection)
         {
         <li>
           <input type="checkbox" value="@t.id"/>
         </li>
         }
</ul>
```

On the JavaScript (Jquery) side, I have this:

```
$('#containerDIV').on('change', '#CheckBoxList', function (event) {

    var id = $(this).val(); // this gives me null
    if (id != null) {
      //do other things
    }

});
```

It's clear that `$this` is not the checkbox, it's the div `containerDIV` or `checkBoxList`

How can I get to the checkbox's state and value?

Comment: `event.target` would be the dom element which triggered the change event

Comment: @billyonecan this should work, but I'm trying to get the right syntax

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your `input` is not being created dynamically after the DOM loads you can just call:

```
$('#CheckBoxList input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {

  var id = $(this).val(); // this gives me null
  if (id != null) {
    //do other things
  }

});
```

or to use `.on()` you just need to target the `input` that's getting clicked:

```
$('#CheckBoxList').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {

  var id = $(this).val(); // this gives me null
  if (id != null) {
    //do other things
  }

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljsyj8ef/)

Comment: I can't do that, the view is a partial view, and when it gets replaced, I loose the "binding" between JQUERY and the DOM

Comment: @216 look at the second example i posted

Comment: @216 added a fiddle too

Answer (score 10):

The way i got it to work correctly was using `.is(':checked')`.

```
$('selector').change(function (e) {
        // checked will equal true if checked or false otherwise
        const checked = $(this).is(':checked')); 
});
```

Comment: This is more better approach.

Answer (score 2):

If you can, add the events as an attribute, like `onchange='function(this);'`.  This returns the element to the function, so you can get data such as it's ID, or just modify it like that.

---

## Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Following  billyonecan comment, this is another way to do it:

```
$('#containerDIV').on('change', '#CheckBoxList', function (event) {

var id =$(event.target).val();
if (id != null) {
  //do other things
}

});
```